# Keyboard Layout Not US after installing fcitx

Tags: keyboard, language

So I installed fcitx and installed a Japanese font, (Anthy). When I turn it off to type with my US layout keyboard, the special characters are mixmatched. the colon key makes a +. The equality key returns a ^.

I went to system settings > keyboard and found that I was, according to the system, with the US layout.

Any idea how to restore the keyboard layout to default, or how to access the config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's used in the second field of the layout? Maybe you can change it to default there. (Or simply delete your current layout and add a fresh one)

[image]

Comment: I tried upvoting your answer but don't have the rep. You helped a lot! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If it's the answer to your question you can mark it as correct (should be possible with all reputations)

Answer (score 0):

I did what @Eric G suggested, but I deleted the old layout setting, so that I didn't have any layouts, and clicked that plus button, went down to my language (US English) and selected default. Everything seems to be working! Thanks Eric!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
(Not for my reputation, but for anyone searching for something like this in the future, so he knows at a glance, that this answer should be working)